# Use C# anonymous object to generate a json string where the property name is not a legal C# variable name

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

To succinctly generate the json string `{"limit": 1}` in C#, I can serialize an equivalent anonymous object like so:

```
var s = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { limit = 1 });
```

What if I want to to generate `{"$limit": 1}` instead? Is there any way of doing that with an anonymous object, or do I have to bring out the big guns?

Comment: I don't think so. You could [use a `@` prefix to get names that match language keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names#naming-rules), and there are tricks to emit IL, which allows for some names that would be illegal in C# proper, but nothing to fix a name that is otherwise illegal.

Comment: You can either define a named type and add attributes to use "illegal" names, or use a dictionary instead of an anonymous type and use "illegal" names for the keys.

Comment: How about just make a dictionary instead?

Comment: Ironically, in very old versions of Basic, a dollar sign used to represent a string, but it was always on the end (e.g. `Dim MyName$`) ... though I know this isn't helpful here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt that there is a way to achieve this with anonymous objects.

You can use `JsonNode` API introduced in .NET 6 for `System.Text.Json` (the succinct syntax uses [indexer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode.item?view=net-6.0) and implicit conversion [from `int` to `JsonNode`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode.op_implicit?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-nodes-jsonnode-op-implicit(system-nullable((system-int32)))-system-text-json-nodes-jsonnode)):

```cs
var serialize = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new JsonObject{["$limit"] = 1});
```

Other options: use dictionaries or create a type and use [`JsonPropertyNameAttribute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=net-6.0) (I assume this one is mentioned as "big guns") .

Comment: Actually that's not bad at all, better than I was expecting. Much less ugly than Dictionary<string, object>, and the shorter dictionary initialisation syntax helps a lot too, so overall it's not too incongruous when mixed into an anonymous object where necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new Dictionary<string, int> { { "$limit", 1 } });
```

result

```
{"$limit":1}
```

or even more complicated

```
var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> { { "$limit0", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "$limit", 1 } } }});

//or 
var s = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "$limit0", new { limit = 1 } } });
```

results

```
{"$limit0":{"$limit":1}}

//or
{"$limit0":{"limit":1}}
```

Comment: How about with this tweak of your solution... `JsonSerializer.Serialize(new Dictionary<string, int> { { $"${nameof(limit)}", 1 } });`

Comment: @quaabaam You have to define limit at first. The chalenge is to put everything in one line. You can use a const as well